# Instagram Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to like the Instagram posts and add comments on the post.NET C#

I have an access token get from Instagram this token is working on getting user information and published post.

When trying to like or comment on post with same access token getting error
Here is my post request

> [https://instagram.com/media/"MYPOSTID"/likes?access_token="MYACESSTOEKN"](https://instagram.com/media/%22MYPOSTID%22/likes?access_token=%22MYACESSTOEKN%22)

here is error:

> {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}

I'm using Instagram basic display app with a tester account.

If anyone has an idea please share.

Comment: Tokens are usually passed in HTTP headers, not querystring parameters - are you sure you're passing it correctly?

Comment: @Dai 
Thanks for replying,
On other API calls, I'm passing the same.